# Wild bug with an icon font - wrong icon displayed

Tags: css, fonts, icons

(Ask to answer)

For the project I'm working on we have a custom set of icons, which I converted into a font using https://glyphter.com/ (just googled this type of service and it seemed okay).

Inside one of the block I'm inserting an icon with the class from the CSS generated by the service (like you normally do with an icon font).
And suddenly the displayed icon is wrong - though the `content` property is okay.
Also could not find any other interfering styles which could do that.

Sorry, no code here, got no time for that. Also the project is quite restricted in terms of sharing details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after half a day of looking for a problem and trying different scenarios, it appeared, that **the icon font generated had the same icons for the letters in both upper and lower case**. And yes, the set **started on the letters**, not with an extended UTF-8 table (or whatever).

So the parent element had `text-transform: uppercase` which changed the icon without changing the `content` or else.
Maybe someone will find this info helpful.

Comment: I had the same issue and found the cause quickly due to this post - thanks for answering your own question